# Kata's for Statistics

Tags: statistics

In programming one way at getting better at common problems is solving them in different ways with exercises known as 'kata'. I was wondering, since I'm long out of school, are there available exercises for statistics to increase ones math ability outside of just doing the same problems over and over again out of a textbook?

Comment: I was looking at that downvote. If not here, where to ask such a question ?

Comment: In what kind of statistics are in interested, e.g. computational statistics, mathematical statistics, applied statistics (ofc there is no strict boundary between those)...? What do you consider as getting better and what background do you have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Statistics" is a fairly broad field. You could pick up a standard undergraduate probability/statistics textbook, flip to the later chapters, and have a source of new problems for months. (Later chapters on mathematical statistics are often more about proving and less about rote calculations, if you have the right book.) You haven't mentioned much of your background, so this might be appropriate and/or fun.

But since you specifically asked to avoid textbooks, let me offer an alternative suggestion: Lower-level actuarial exams. These exams are mostly about undergraduate probability, and there are a [wealth of sample questions available online](https://www.soa.org/Files/Edu/edu-exam-p-sample-quest.pdf). Since these exams are taken under time constraints, your "kata" could be finding the fastest way to solve these problems.